# Add a dynamic button to a dynamic gridview in android?

Tags: android, button, gridview

My initial approach--
I am creating some buttons lets say 5 button at runtime.
I store them in a vector.

I need to add these buttons in a dynamic grid. I have added my dynamic button in the xml.
I pass the vector buttons to the adapter class.
But what i cant figure out is how do I add that button to the gridview.

This is my adapter class

```
   public class GridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Vector<LinkButton> gridButton;

    public GridAdapter() {
        gridButton = null;
    }

    public GridAdapter(Vector<LinkButton> gg) {
        Log.e("view   ", "grid");
        gridButton = gg;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return gridButton.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return return gridButton.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View row;
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_element, parent, false);
        LinkButton lb = gridButton.get(position);

        Log.e("viewGrid   ", ""+gridButton.get(position));
        ((ViewGroup) row).addView(lb);

        return row;
    }

}
```

This is how i am calling the constructor

```
  GridView g = new GridView(this);
        g.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        g.setNumColumns(2);
        g.setAdapter(new GridAdapter(homeButtons));
```

Answer (score 0):

use following code:

```
 @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View row;
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_element, parent, false);  //xml layout which contains the dynamic button element
        LinkButton lb   = gridButton.get(position);
        LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        ((ViewGroup) row).addView(lb , lp);            

        return row;
    }
```

Comment: there is no method addview() for row

Comment: what is your mean about not Working? don't add view to your layout? get Exception?

Comment: i test this code and it's working, maybe problem is with your `LinkButton`, replace that with simple `TextView` and `setText` to that and show result

Comment: I think there is some problem with the getView it is not being called

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45623/discussion-between-shayan-pourvatan-and-wishy)

Comment: @Wishy test this code on one layout that have `gridView`, that means don't create `gridView` dynamically too